# Calling a value from database and then use it as <title>

Tags: php

I am trying to use f_n as the page title. However, it keeps popping up that the variable fn is not defined.

```
$pageTitle = $fn;
$fn = "";

if(isset($_GET['f_n']))
{
  if(DB::query('SELECT f_n FROM users WHERE f_n=:f_n', array(':f_n'=> $fn)))
  {
    $fn = DB::query('SELECT f_n FROM users WHERE f_n=:f_n', array(':f_n'=> $fn))[0]['f_n'];
  }
}
```

I've now tried:

```
$fn = DB::query('SELECT f_n FROM users WHERE f_n=:f_n', array(':f_n' => $fn));
$pageTitle = $fn;
$dir = '../timeline/index.php';
require_once('../classes/DB.php');
include '../classes/Login.php';
```

But now it pops up:
 `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mostWanted\profile\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mostWanted\profile\index.php on line 2`

Comment: Your first line of code is referencing `$fn` and it's not been defined yet...

Comment: Also, don't run the query twice, that's really unnecessary and non-performant. Save the result of the query to a variable, then reference the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$fn` is not defined.

Try:

`$pageTitle = $_GET['f_n'];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code might be the sequence of declaration of the variables.
Original Sequence :

```
$pageTitle = $fn;
$fn = "";
```

You have used $fn before even declaring it hence the error. Try reversing the sequence.

```
$fn = "";
$pageTitle = $fn;
```

Comment: I've tried that but then there's no page title at all